# Silverlight: How to bind to the other control itself; Not the control's property

Tags: silverlight, binding

I have a user control which got a property pointing to other control say textbox.

e.g. in XAML

```
<MyControl TheTextBox="{Binding ????}" />


<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" />
```

How to set TheTextBox to be MyTextBox in XAML?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
<MyControl TheTextBox="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBox}"/>
```